# How to detect restart event in App delegate - OSX?

Tags: swift, macos

I want to quit the application only at the event of restart / logoff. Is there any way to find logoff/restart in OSX ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an observer on `NSWorkspace` watching for `NSWorkspaceWillPowerOff`:

```
NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(yourMethod),
                                                    name: .NSWorkspaceWillPowerOff,
                                                    object: nil)
```

Here `yourMethod` will be called whenever the Mac is powering off (reboot or shutdown).

There's also notifications for going to sleep: `NSWorkspaceWillSleep` and for waking up: `NSWorkspaceDidWake`.